# Declaring a global variable and storing a value in it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and am trying to track the changes a user made on this form.
 The form consist of radio buttons, dropdown and text area which are loaded when
 the user selects the first dropdown.

I then decided to count. If the user selects the dropdown again meaning the second time
 something has changed.

I want to be able to store result = 1 in a Global variable so that it can be used by another
 function on the same page/same view. My application is mvc

How can I store this global variable on the view so that other javascript functions can use it? Is this possible?

```
         var counter = 0;
                $("#MyPage")
                        .on("change", ":input", function () {              
                            counter = counter + 1;
                            if (counter > 1) {
                                //This is the first time you are changing.
                                alert("Something has changed in index page");                       
                                var result = 1;
                            }
                });
```

Comment: i would just push the logs to an array instead of maintaining a counter...

Comment: `window.foo = bar`

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing with the above implementation?

Comment: I want to be able to access a variable globally.

Comment: @gcampbell - what does the window.foo = bar imply? What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @user2320476 That's how you set global variables in a browser environment.

Comment: @dandavis - If I push to an array, how can I make that available globally to other functions?

Comment: @user2320476 You can also store that array like this
window.variable_name = array
this makes your variable global and you can use it any where like this
window.variable_name

Answer (score -2):

Simply use `result = 1`, without `var` in front

Edit: ssube is correct, use the above method.

Comment: Declaring a variable outside of a function *does not* give it global scope. It simply picks up the module or script it was declared in. This confusion may have come from w3schools, which provides very poor (and sometimes plain wrong) examples. Please do not use them as a reference.

Comment: this answer is right, it's just poor practice; suggesting "implicit globals", which are typically a mistake.